# Complexity Of Insert in a young tableau

Tags: arrays, sorting, matrix, time-complexity

Consider I have a young tableau like this ->

```
10 11 12 15
16 18 20 22
25 27 30 34
35 40 44 Infinity
```

**Infinity denotes an empty element**

- I have an algorithm where, I place the element at the bottom right, then shift it as upwards as possible and then as left as possible.
- I insert 8.

```
10 11 12 15
16 18 20 22
25 27 30 34
35 40 44 8
```

- Move it as up as possible and then as left as possible. 15,22,34 are displaced.

```
 8 10 11 12
16 18 20 15
25 27 30 22
35 40 44 34
```

- Now after coming back from the recursive call, I place 15 at it's correct place. The 22 at it's correct place. Then 34 at it's correct place.

```
 8 10 11 12
15 16 18 20
22 25 27 30
34 35 40 44
```

According to me , the time complexity of the whole operation is O(m*n) where m,n are the dimensions of the matrix.
Algorithm

1. Place the element at bottom right corner.
2. Move it as upwards as possible.
3. Then move it as left as possible.
4. After the recursive call completes, place the displaced elements at their right place.

Am I correct in finding the time complexity? O(m*n)

Comment: I don't understand where the recursive part is, but moving a single element to its place is O(m+n) in my opinion, and then you do it k times.

Comment: What is k here?

Comment: Well, I obtained the same answer as yours when I read the CLRS book. I agree with your analysis of complexity---O(mn). Some solutions claim an O(m+n) algorithm, e.g., https://www.techiedelight.com/young-tableau-insert-search-extract-min-delete-replace/, but a simple experiment shows that the complexity should be O(mn). In fact I wonder whether there exist an O(m+n) algorithm of this problem.